# How to plot the confidence intervals of a Fourier spectrum

Tags: python, matplotlib, fft, confidence-interval

Hello I am trying to plot the confidence interval (CI) using the style of this figure: vertical lines that indicates the CI width [image: Figure taken from "The 2011 Tohoku Tsunami on the Coast of Mexico: A Case Study" article]. As you know the default style is a interval is a band around the line. Anyone could help me to do this?

I attached the following code of my fourier spectrum of sea level data and the [sea_level.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mVs01_sOU5YyVSUYhi-p2dV3COBLcm8x/view?usp=share_link):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
from scipy import signal

# Loading the data

aca_level = pd.read_csv('path/sea_level.txt',sep=" ") 
aca_level['Nivel'] = aca_level['Nivel'].fillna(0)
sea_level = aca_level.iloc[2074324:2074324+2048,1]
#................... Calculating the FT
N = 2048 # Number of data
L = 4  # Number of blocks
M = N/L # Data number of each block
fs = 60 # Sampling frecuency

the_window = signal.windows.kaiser(M, beta=5)
f_ts,esp_ts = signal.welch(sea_level,fs,window=the_window, nperseg=M,noverlap= M//2,scaling='density')
#................... Ploting
fig = plt.figure() 
plt.loglog(f_ts,esp_ts,color="black",lw=1.5)
plt.plot()
```